# emberjs unable to save or create a new record with emberjs- 1.0.0-rc.1 and ember-data revision-11

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create a simple blog app with emberjs. The feature for creating a title and body for the post works fine as seen in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CD9ck/)**.

Now I want to add the next feature which is comments, which should be displayed when you click on an individual post. on the home page, click post then clicking the title of an individual, should show a comment box to add comments.

**I get the following error when I click the save button**

**On my local develop environment using ember-data and the rest adapter**, I get the error:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'commit' of undefined
```

**In JSfiddle using the fixture adapter** with thesame code, the error becomes

```
TypeError: this.transaction is undefined this.transaction.commit();
```

posts/show.handlebars

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/show">
      <h1>Post</h1>
      <p>Your content here.</p>
       <h3> {{title}} </h3>
       <h3> {{body}} </h3>
     </br>
    <p> {{#linkTo 'posts.index'}} back {{/linkTo}}</p>
    <p> {{#linkTo 'posts.edit' content}} Edit the post  {{/linkTo}}</p> 
    <br/>
     <p> Add Comments</p>
      {{render 'comment/new' comments}}
   </script>
```

comment/new.handlebars

```
 <form {{action save on='submit'}}>
   {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding='body' placeholder='body'}}
   <button type="submit"> Add comment </button>
 </form>

  EmBlog.CommentNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
     needs: ['posts'],
     addComment: function(){
       post = this.get('controllers.postsShow').get('model');
       comment = post.get('comments')
       this.transaction = comment.get('store').transaction.createRecord({body: body});
     },

     save: function(){
       this.transaction.commit();
     }  
   });

 EmBlog.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
   body: DS.attr('string'),
   post_id: DS.attr('integer')'
   post:  DS.belongsTo('EmBlog.Post')
 });
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this in way that every time I create a comment it will include the post_id.

```
 **Update**
```

This is the **[latest gist](http://jsfiddle.net/CD9ck/4/)**, it doesn't display any error when I save comment but the comments don't appear on the page. It seems they are silently ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`DS.Store#transaction` is a function, not a property. It returns a `DS.Transaction`... however, you are calling `createRecord` on it immediately, so you're actually storing the result of that call (a record) in your transaction property. Additionally, `createRecord` on a `DS.Transaction` requires a type as the first parameter.

Because this is an ObjectController we have to define our internal properties in our class definition, otherwise they'll get passed through to the content.

```
EmBlog.CommentNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    transaction: null,
```

And then in your actual code:

```
var transaction = post.get('store').transaction();
if (transaction) {
    this.set('transaction', transaction);
    transaction.createRecord(EmBlog.Comment, {body: body});
} else { console.log('store.transaction() returned null'); }
```

then later:

```
this.get('transaction').commit();
```

Note that the comment won't be automatically scoped to the `Post`, so make sure to set your relationships.

Comment: Many thanks @christopher for helping out. I used your code snippet above to replace the relevant parts of my jsfiddle but it still returned a new error **TypeError: this.transaction is undefined**. Thanks for any new suggestion

Comment: Because you're using an objectController, the controller will try to set that property on its content. You need to define 'transaction' as a property on the controller when you define it.

Comment: Thanks @christopher. I defined 'transaction' as a property on the controller and had this error. When I defined it in the controller as **transaction: ' '**, it returns the error: **TypeError: this.transaction.commit is not a function**. But when it is defined as
**transaction: null**, it returns the error: **TypeError: this.transaction is null**

Comment: I updated my anwer to fix a small problem and to add a little test to ensure reality is matching expectations.

Comment: @Thanks for being patient teacher. I have updated the fiddle with your code and here is the new link: **http://jsfiddle.net/CD9ck/1/**. When I try to create a new comment, it returns the error: **TypeError: this.get(...) is null**. Will turning the controller into an arraycontroller help?

Comment: You never call your addComment method.

Comment: thanks. I am now calling the addComment method from the template. There are 2 issues now depending on what version of transaction i use. Since the addComment is in the **CommentNewController**, clicking addComment returns **ReferenceError: post is not defined**. If I change that by using the needs api **needs: ['posts']** and changing how i define transaction to use the **[injected controller](http://jsfiddle.net/CD9ck/3/)**, then we get back thesame old error: **TypeError: this.get(...) is undefined** which we were getting before I began calling addComment method in the template.

Comment: I have eliminated all the errors and the comment form now appears when i **[click addComment](http://jsfiddle.net/CD9ck/4/)**, however, when i click save, it saves without error but the saved comment does not show on the page. **No error are displayed**.

Comment: I decided log what happens when I click save and it shows undefined.

Comment: I also decided to  log where I defined transaction: **var transaction = console.log(this.get('store').transaction());** and it turned out that the real problem seems to be **TypeError: transaction.createRecord is not a function**.

Comment: Well then something is off because createRecord is indeed a function on DS.Transaction